# как писать в pywinauto в свёрнутом окне

Tags: python, автоматизация, pywinauto

мне нужно реализовать скрипт который будет писать в свёрнутом окне какой нибудь текст например блокнот. Библиотека pyautowin вот мой код:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start("notepad.exe")
dlg = app.window(title="Безымянный – Блокнот")
dlg.type_keys("Я{SPACE}крутой{SPACE}бот{ENTER}")
dlg = app.window(title="*Безымянный – Блокнот")
for i in range(100):
    dlg.type_keys("Я{SPACE}крутой{SPACE}бот{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать методы `.send_chars` и `.send_keystrokes` (он умеет немного больше комбинаций клавиш) вместо `.type_keys`. Правда эти два метода могут работать не для всех приложений, так что гарантий никаких.

Для кликов есть метод `.click()` вместо `.click_input()`.

Если по работе нужно запускать GUI automation удалённо, то можно настроить RDP или юзать VNC правильно. Тогда можно любые методы юзать. Основные рецепты все тут: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html). Если для хобби, то виртуалка как вариант, хотя и накладно.